# How to let a handler, which syncs with the main looper, wait for more data

Tags: android, android-handler, android-thread

When a new object from the Database arrives, a new Handler will be created which posts the object to the UI thread so that the UI processes and draws the object.

```
    public void notify(MyObject myObject) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    myview.handleUpdate(myObject); 
                }
        };
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
```

This works perfectly but when 100 messages come in at a the same time, 100 threads will be created and this creates a bottleneck.

I would like to let the handler wait for 2 seconds before it starts, so it can wait for other objects.

I've tried the following but this doesn't work. The thread will be initiated but waits 2 seconds for other objects which will be added to the list. When the time is over the thread will be posted to the main thread with all the objects.

```
    boolean wait = false;
    ArrayList<MyObject> myObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void notify(MyObject myObject) {
        if(wait) {
            myObjectList.add(myObject); // handler waits already, just add the object to the list
            return;
        }

        wait = true; // says that the handler waits for data
        myObjectList.add(myObject);
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thread.sleep(2000); // wait for 2 seconds
                    myview.handleUpdate(new ArrayList<>(myObjectList)); 
                    wait = false; // posted, a new handler can be created
                    myObjectList.clear(); 
                }
        };
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
```

Comment: use `Handler#postDelayed` instead

Comment: wow, thanks! I see, theres a big difference between postDelayed and sleep. Sadly I'm not able to mark this as correct answer

Comment: Where do you create these new Threads? I only see a "post()" on the MainThread. Calling that "post()" 1000 times doesn't create 1000 Threads, but it just posts Runnables in the MainThread's queue. However a better solution is to create a HandlerThread (using "new HandlerThread()") and you post those Runnables to is Handler. After every post() you have to post an additional postDelay(SEND_TO_UI, 2000) that will remove the previous one. In this way when the HandlerThread process the SEND_TO_UI message it means that there are not arrived any other post() within last 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 2 seceonds
      }
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void notify(MyObject myObject) {// this is the ONLY method on WORKER THREAD
            waitList.add(myObject);
 }

ArrayList<MyObject> waitList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

Handler handler = new Handler();// main thread handler

Runnable runCheck = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {// runs on main thread
             if(checking){
                 for(Iterator<MyObject> iter = waitList.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ){
                      myview.handleUpdate((MyObject)iter.next());
                      iter.remove();
                       // instead of removing you can add a boolean (dirty) 
                       //to MyObject and set it to false to flag it as considered object
                      //in this way you do not need to change list from multiple threads
                 } 
                 checkWaitList();// check for new items 2 seconds later
             }
 }
 private void checkWaitList(){// runs on main thread
      if(checking)
           handler.postDelayed(runCheck, 2000);
 }

 private boolean checking;

 private void startChecking(){// runs on main thread
    if(!checking){
        checking = true;
        checkWaitList();
    }
 }
 private void stopChecking(){// runs on main thread
    checking = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runCheck);
 }
```